# Accidentally switched from Microsoft Teams to Skype for Business, now I can't use Microsoft Teams to send messages

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

I can no longer use Microsoft Teams to send messages. My coworkers get a message in Teams telling them to go to Skype for business to send messages to me.

I see a message icon while Teams desktop is starting for a few seconds, but it goes away. And also I see a dialog box at the bottom disabled with a message saying "Administrator has disabled chat for this user."

How do I switch back to Microsoft Teams for messaging?

Comment: Please contact your administrator to check if you disabled Private Chat. Refer to [Microsoft Teams: Disable Private Chat (How To)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/skypehybridguy/2017/08/24/microsoft-teams-disable-private-chat-how-to/)